# VS2008 SSRS using to query Oracle: How do I stop {oj} for outer Joins?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I am using VS2008 SSRS to query and report a Oracle Database. 
Whenever I the query Designer to add an outer join it adds {oj} 
e.g.

OJ Added

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM {oj A LEFT OUTER JOIN B On A.id = B.id}
```

OJ Not added(How I want it)

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B On A.id = B.id
```

The only way I can get the query to run is to "Edit as Text..." and remove the {oj...}

Is there any way of stopping Visual Studio 2008 from adding the {oj} when I want an outer join, without having to "Edit as Text"

Comment: We couldn't get outer joins to work at all. Anyone out there with a solution?

Comment: `{ OJ` is valid syntax for [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html), but not [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDIJFDJ).

Comment: I almost invariably write my queries from scratch, for reasons including the above. If I write it the way I want it, the designers don't mess with it. :-)

Comment: I have resolved this issue and try with Microsoft OLEDB driver for connecting Oracle.

Comment: Where is the edit as test option? I am using 2010

Comment: If you have already created a dataset, right click on it then pick query from the menu. Then in the query designer that appears the button is in top left. If it a new data set you can keep query type as text and just type the query in the query box

Comment: VS 2017 adds the { oj } when I just paste an LEFT JOIN into the on-the-fly query interface. I came here from Googling for how I could stop it from doing that. Clearly nobody has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have yet to find a solution.  I am pretty sure the Oracle driver for SSRS is just plain wrong - there is no problem with SQL Server data sources.  I can't believe there aren't more people complaining about it.

It used to work, but used the old style (+) syntax for outer joins, until a year or so ago.  I guess at that point there was some update which attempted to change it to the newer syntax, but blew it by including the curly bracket oj, which seems to be the normal syntax for some other sources, but it certainly doesn't work with Oracle.

Yes, of course you can edit it in the text query designer, but if you switch to the graphical designer it immediately re-inserts the curly brackets etc.  I like to have the graphical option and it really ought to work!

The issue has been with our suppliers since it first occurred, but they seem quite unable to grasp the problem.  They occasionally email me to ask if the problem still exists! I guess they are hoping for a miracle.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN Says that the `{oj}` syntax should work in Visual Studio. However, it also says that the `(+)` syntax also works. So you can try-

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
  FROM A , B 
 WHERE A.id = B.id(+);
```

While the query below will work in Visual Studio, it will not not work only any Oracle DB Client tools (Toad, SQL Developer, SQL prompt etc.).

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM {oj A LEFT OUTER JOIN B On A.id = B.id};
```

Comment: Have you tried any of this in the report designer and not the full Visual Studio development environment?

Comment: I tried the above question in full Visual Studio development and just in Business Intelligence Studio enviroment. Both with the same results.

Comment: Annjawn: The issue isn't with the SQL, as we can enter that via "Edit as Text". It more what the VS Designers automatically produced SQL, that I want to change, so that {oj} isn't used.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? if the SQL is meant to run on VS then it should probably have the `{oj}` syntax. VS should not throw errors with the `{oj}` syntax specifically, but there are a couple of limitations to outer joins mentioned in MSDN. If you want to run the SQL in a SQL Tool (SQLPlus, Toad, SQLDeveloper) you will have to use `(+)` syntax.

Comment: I am sadly constrained by the available tools at my work. I don't mind writing the SQL by hand and using the `(+)` syntax. We used to (VS2005) be able to use the query designers to produce SQL that was vaild for Oracle. So I was hoping in VS2008 there was an option to change; a way of extending the designer or altering the Oracle Driver to deal with the issue. Hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: Not sure why the two VS versions would be functionally different. You can use Oracle's SQL Developer too for the purpose of query design http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Querybuilder/sqldev3.0_QB.htm

Answer (score 1):

One of our guys finally found that if you go into edit text mode you can strip out the {oj and then save the query. (In our case a named query)  As long as you don't go back into visual mode in the report designer it will keep the edited query and works fine. However, if you flip over into visual mode the {oj comes back again.

Comment: Yeah we found that, but as the question says we are needing a solution which doesnt require "edit as text..."